# Why can't I use my other commands after this rockpaperscissors one in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am writing a Discord bot but whenever I use this ,rockpaperscissors command, after the game has finished I can't use any of my other commands like ,help. Why is this?

````
        elif message.content == ",rockpaperscissors":
        await message.channel.send("```\nRock Paper Scissors\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nSend your move in the format ,[move] e.g. ,rock\n```")
        @client.event
        async def on_message(message):
            _ = str(message.content).lower()[1::]
            computer = random.choice(RPS)
            await rockPaperScissorsChecker(message, _, computer)
            return
````

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to tell from the code that you've given, but here are a couple possibilities of what might be causing it.

---

**Scenario #1**
You have multiple `on_message` events.

When using events, you don't need to write multiple ones - you can use `if`/`elif` statements to your advantage. If you do choose to have multiple, then the one that's been defined the latest in the script will be the "active" one.

Here's how to separate commands in `on_message`:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    elif message.content.lower().startswith(",rockpaperscissors"):
        # code for the cmd here
    elif message.content.lower().startswith(",cmd2"):
        # second cmd code here
    # etc. etc.
```

---

**Scenario #2**
You're using command decorators and `on_message` without processing the commands.

When overriding (writing your own) `on_message` event, you need to call `Bot.process_commands()` in order for the registered commands to work. Behind the scenes there's a default `on_message` event which has this already done, but because you're rewriting your own, you'll need to add it:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    # rest of your on_message code
```

---

**References:**

- [`on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)
- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) - "By default, this coroutine is called inside the `on_message()` event. If you choose to override the `on_message()` event, then you should invoke this coroutine as well."
- [`commands.Command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command) - The command decorator.